# How to modify multiple images in terminal?

Tags: command-line, gimp, convert, png

I need to invert multiple `.png` images from black to white using command line.

I have found that I might use gimp plugin "plug-in-vinvert" but I can not figure out how to use it. I have tried something like

```
gimp -b '(plug-in-vinvert "INT32" "filename.png" "/resultsFolder/")'
```

and many other combinations but with no success.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why gimp? Try `imagemagick` package. It's a great command line image processor.
In your case you can use it like:

```
convert -negate src.png dst.png
```

To modify multiple files at once, e.g.

```
img_path=./path/to/imgs
img_results=./path/to/imgs/results
mkdir -p $img_results
for img in ${img_path}/*;
    do 
    convert -negate $img ${img_results}/${img#./*};
done
```

The exact method may depend on how you source your paths.

Here's an actual example...

```
$ for img in ./png-64/*; do echo convert -negate $img results/${img#./*}; done
convert -negate ./png-64/arrow-block.png results/png-64/arrow-block.png
convert -negate ./png-64/arrow-block-rotated.png results/png-64/arrow-block-rotated.png
convert -negate ./png-64/arrow-shrink.png results/png-64/arrow-shrink.png
```

Comment: It works, except it converts only one file.

Comment: Add loop:
`for i in \`ls *.jpg\`; do convert ${i%.*}.png ${i%.*}-inverted.png; done`

Comment: I have tried your code, but it is not working for me. I guess I am doing some stupid mistake, because I am quite new with Linux. I paste your code directly into terminal and when i press enter, all I get is ">".

Comment: Are you sure you have copied the whole string? From `for` to `done`? 
BTW, there is a mistake in the string: not `*.jpg`, but `*.png`. So the right one: `for i in \`ls *.png\`; do convert ${i%.*}.png ${i%.*}-inverted.png; done`

Comment: I was not working because I have copied it without the "done". You have there one small error, but the working code is `for i in \`ls *.png\`; do convert -negate  ${i%.*}.png results/${i%.*}.png; done`  I have just added `-negate` and changed the code to place the inverted images into "results" folder.

Comment: Ok) BTW, if you put the output in another folder you can use `$i` instead of `${i%.*}`. `${i%.*}` only necessary if you want to use filename without extension. In our case it allowed us to change the filenames from e.g. "name.png" to "name-inverted.png"

Comment: Thanks. In that case the final code is `for i in \`ls *.png\`; do convert -negate  $i results/$i; done`

Comment: [don't parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead), use `for i in *.png; do ...`

Answer (score 5):

To **convert a batch of images**, the fastest and shortest way I know is to use the following **ImageMagick** command:

```
mogrify -negate *.jpg
```

N.B. Change image format accordingly and **make sure you have a copy** of the original images.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! For me, it was `magick mogrify -negate *.png` as `mogrify` does not seem to be a directly callable (archlinux)

Answer (score 1):

Try this GIMP plugin for performing a routine on multiple images simultaneously: "Batch Image Manipulation Plugin" http://registry.gimp.org/node/26259

Download and extract the package, open a terminal inside the resulting folder, and run:

```
make && make install
```

Then start Gimp, go to *File - Batch Image Manipulation*, in order to start the plugin. There you can add the multiple images.

[image]

As the question asks for inverting colors, add the corresponding manipulation set: *Add - Other GIMP procedure*, search for 'invert' and you will find 'gimp-invert'

[image]

OK, and before 'Apply' you can set the output folder which by default is `~/`.

Hope that helps. Have fun GIMPing!